# Getting java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob error in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using declarative pipeline wherein when I build my pipeline it is giving me `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob` error.

These are the 2 methods which I am using:-

```
@NonCPS
def getJob(name) {
    def hi = Hudson.instance
    return hi.getItemByFullName(name, Job)
}

@NonCPS
def getParam(WorkflowJob job, String paramName) {
    def prop = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
    for (param in prop.getParameterDefinitions()) {
        if (param.name == paramName) {
            return param
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

And below is the part of my code where I am getting this error.

```
stages{
        stage("A"){
            steps{
                
                script {
                    
                    def job = getJob(JOB_NAME)
                    def param = getParam(job, "AWS Ser")
                    def service_name = ("${SERVICE_NAME}".replace('AWS Ser:', '')).toString().tokenize(',[]')
                    if (service_name != 'All') {
                        
                        def regions = "${REGIONS}".toString()
                        regions.split('\n').each() {
                            service_name.each() {
                                
                                sh '''
                                    echo "Welcome"
                                '''
                                    
                                

                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
```

Here, if you see when I put sh script then I get this error and if I remove this sh script then there is no error.

I tried to troubleshoot and something is wrong with the 2 methods which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return the `WorkflowJob` object to the Pipeline step. Refactor your functions like below.

```
@NonCPS
def getJob(name) {
    def hi = Hudson.instance
    return hi.getItemByFullName(name, Job)
}

@NonCPS
def getParam(String jobName, String paramName) {
    def job = getJob(jobName)
    def prop = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
    for (param in prop.getParameterDefinitions()) {
        if (param.name == paramName) {
            return param
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Then in the Pipeline stage call getParam as.

```
def param = getParam(JOB_NAME, "AWS Ser")
```